# Removing unwanted margin / padding from embedded content

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, soundcloud

I have embedded a SoundCloud widget on my page below an image.

There is a small space between the bottom of the image and the top of the widget. I've used Web Inspector to track down where this gap is coming from but I cannot find it. I would like to remove this space.

The code is quite simple:

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Image-New_Delhi_Lotus.jpg">
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F66379982?"></iframe>
```

View the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/LAn3A/

I can't even tell if this gap is due to a border, padding or a margin. I am certain it is coming from the SoundCloud widget though.

Comment: Embeded iframes usually don't add padding/margin around. It might be your CSS that adds margin or padding. Look at your code in this sandbox website: http://jsbin.com/ulotun/1/edit  there is no margin around the widget.

Comment: There actually _is_ a space around the widget in the code in the website you just posted. Look very closely above the widget! http://i.imgur.com/jdyKf.png

Comment: So padding is NOT around the iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when you try closely position an inline element next to a block-level element.  Text properties such as line-height get in the way.  Fix it by setting the image to a block level element:

```
img { display: block;}
```

Comment: Wonderful! You solved it. For bonus points, could you explain why this happens exactly?

Comment: Image is an inline element, that is you can think of it as of a letter or a word in a line of text. There are CSS properties that affect inline elements, such as `line-height`, `vertical-align` (both set on parent elements) and the way they are laid out. So in this case default line height set on parent element affects the line containing the image.